# jquery on page load flicker effect for div display none/block based on session state

Tags: jquery, css

I have a session that checks if the div was opened or closed. If it's closed, on page load the div would flicker open the close as it checked the state and closed it.

Is there a way to make it instant so the flicker/flash of open then close goes away?

I can't see the problem on jsfiddle but it does do the flicker on my localhost and my server online

```
$(function() {

    $('.target').each(function(i, v){
        var $i = i + 1;
        $(v).toggleClass('hidden',
         sessionStorage.getItem('form_visible' + $i) != 'true');
    });

    $('.slide').click(function(ev){
        var $ev = $(ev.currentTarget);
        var $next = $ev.next();

         $next.slideToggle('slow', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
         });
         debugger;   
         sessionStorage.setItem('form_visible' + $ev.attr("id"), $next.hasClass('hidden'));
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/2ADsL/3/**

My scripts are located at the footer of every page.

Please help me out!

Comment: you can try (fast) instead of (slow). -- $next.slideToggle('fast', function() {

Comment: no that still does the open then close flicker. I don't think it's that

Comment: You can add another class that uses a css transition to animate the container. You can try lazy loading the element so when the .setItem is called, then it displays the content. If it's loading via ajax, you could use ajaxComplete or ajaxStop. You can also have it always closed, and then once the JS runs, open it back up (or animate in). The idea here is to give some feedback that there is content, and the animation is to give the user something to look at while it's finishing loading.